D365 DAX Limitations in Formula Column
We use Dynamics CRM in our nonprofit to track donors and donations. I'm trying to add a calculated field to the "donations" table that looks at the donation date and lists the fiscal year that gift falls into.
Does anyone have an idea how I could accomplish this? Since our FY starts on 9/1, I figured I could just have this field figure out the FY by looking at the month, and returning either the current year, or the current year+1.
I tried this:
IF(
MONTH('Donation Date') >= 9, 
"FY" & TEXT(YEAR('Donation Date') + 1, "00"), 
"FY" & TEXT(YEAR('Donation Date'), "00")
)

However, I'm finding that there are a lot of limitations to the DAX code you can use in a formula field in D365. MONTH, YEAR, DAY, TEXT, are all functions that apparently are not supported.
